# Interior of the Inverse of a Continuous Map

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map between metric spaces. Let $A\subset Y$ and let $B=f^{-1}(A)$. Let $C$ denote the interior of $A$ and let $D$ denote the interior of $B$. Can we conclude that $f^{-1}(C)\subset D$? Can we conclude that $D\subset f^{-1}(C)$? Prove or give a counterexample for each case.

I have no clue where to start with this problem.

Comment: Draw a picture it always helps with these inverse maps

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}(C)$ is an open set contained in $B$. and hence is also contained in the interior of $B$. Hence $f^{-1}(C)\subseteq D$.

For the other implication consider the constant map $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $f(x)=0$.

Let $A=\{0\}$, notice that $B=\mathbb R$ and so $D=\mathbb R$. On the other hand $C$ is the empty set, and so is $f^{-1}(C)$.